# style:background-color in <li><a></a></li>

Tags: html, list, styles, underline

```html
<li><a href="#" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 3px;">&thinsp;TEXT&thinsp;</a></li>
```

I want only the "TEXT" to be underlined, not the thin spaces, but the thin spaces must have the background-color. Can someone please help me to successfully do this?

Comment: Then place the spaces outside the <a>-element. (between the li and the a)

Comment: Then where do I need to place the style?

Comment: Place it on the `<li>`? Or, if you need other elements to have other styles, wrap the `<a>` in a `<span>`and put the style on that.

Comment: When I put it on the <li>, the style becomes very long. It is a horizontal menu list.

Comment: Are you serious? Why are you putting things like this in the code? Use an external stylesheet, an id on the container, and so on.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This code here should work.

```
<li>
   <a href="#" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-radius: 3px; text-decoration: none;">&thinsp;<span style="text-decoration: underline;">TEXT</span>&thinsp;</a>
</li>
```

It would also be possible to just put the spaces outside of `<a></a>` and not have the need for a span element.

Comment: The code you sent is almost exactly what I wanted. How do I make the text only be underlined when hovering over it with the mouse?

Comment: Putting the thin spaces outside the `<a></a>` unfortunately doesn't work, the style background color then starts to take up much more space. Maybe because it is a horizontal (menu) list.

Comment: Make a fiddle of what you mean. @user7214787 you should probably use some stylesheets though, for readability.